# Boost: What is the proper idiom to create a group of threads and wait for them all?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'd like to use Boost to create n threads, each invoking a method on an object, and then `join_all` to wait for them all to complete.  I'd expect this would be simple using `thread_group` and `join_all`, but I'm confused about the following:

1. While `thread` allows passing an object and method, `thread_group::create_thread` doesn't.  This can be worked around (as in [How to pass function parameters to boost::thread_groups::create_thread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319009/how-to-pass-function-parameters-to-boostthread-groupscreate-thread) ), but I'm not sure if there's a reason for that difference; if there is, I'd like to know what the rationale is before I steamroll through it.
2. I'm not sure about scope and lifetime of both the thread and the object I'm passing it.  My understanding is that with simple threads, both the `thread` and the passed object can go out of scope with no problem: the actual system thread stays running, and the passed object is copied.  But, here again, `thread_group` seems to complicate this, especially if I need to use `new` (as per that workaround referenced above).
3. Finally, if I do use `new`, who does the `delete`?  I've tried to figure out how to use a smart pointer, but then the delete seems to happen in the for loop, before the `join_all`
   call.

My code so far is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    W w = W(...);
    //threadGroup.create_thread(&W::work, &w); // Won't work, create_thread won't take params
    boost::thread(&W::task, w);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread group with bind.

Below, `w` will be bound *by value* into the bind expression (so it's copied). See e.g. [boost::bind() copies by reference or by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397092/boostbind-copies-by-reference-or-by-value/6397107?s=8|0.0000#6397107)

If your worker is not copyable instead of the `new` approach consider

- using move: `bind(&W::work, std::move(w))` or, just `bind(&W::work, W("some", 42, "args"))`
- using a shared_ptr (boost bind will know how to invoke member functions on it

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52181ac028a50f30)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

static const int numThreads = 10;

struct W {
    W(...) {}

    void work() {
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group tg;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        W w = W("some", 42, "args");
        tg.create_thread(boost::bind(&W::work, &w));
    }

    tg.join_all();
}
```